# Update Email Address in Domino Directory using Excel (CSV) File

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

We are in the process of migrating users from a company we are acquiring from Lotus Notes to Exchange 2013. I need a Lotus Script agent to run on the Domino Directory that uses an Excel file containing a list of internet address (InternetAddress) values and the new forwarding address (MailAddress). The other company will be using Domino for its Directory services for the time being until all the migration is completed. Each week I will likely have a new list of users that have been migrated. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Save the Excel file as a CSV file.
In the first column you have the user name (as it is listed in Notes).
In the second column you have the user's new internet address and in the third one you have the forwarding address.

Then you write a Lotusscript agent to read the CSV file one line at a time. Use view.GetDocumentByKey() to get the person document for each user, then use the ReplaceItemValue() method of the NotesDocument class to save the value in the second column to the field 'InternetAddress' and the value in the third column to 'MailAddress'.
Don't forget to save the document after the update.

Comment: Might want to mention which view to use for the getDocumentByKey call. I believe ($Users) would work.

Comment: Thank you Karl for your quick repsonse

Comment: i'm an exchange admin..not a lotus script programmer. i'll try to struggle through this coding.

Comment: Could you hire a Notes developer on a consultant basis? You will probably need it for other thins related to your migration.